# Passing pointer to member function to parent in c++

Tags: c++

How can I make the following code work? I can't make the members static, Parent doesn't know about Child and I don't have access to boost. The reason I don't use virtual functions is that a Child class should be able to define 1-N handlers.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    void registerFileHandler(string ext, memFuncPtr);
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    Child()
    {
        registerFileHandler("jpg", &Child::loadJpg);
        registerFileHandler("png", &Child::loadPNG);
    }
    void loadJpg(string filename);
    void loadPNG(string filename);
};
```

EDIT:
There were many answers. The ones that works best for me use the keywords erasure, std::bind and std::function which of course rely on c++11. 
Here is a full compilable example:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    void load(string filename)
    {
        // See if we can find a handler based on the extension.
        for(auto it = handlers.begin();it!=handlers.end();it++)
            if(filename.substr(filename.size()-it->first.size(), it->first.size())==it->first)
                it->second(filename);
    }
    template<typename Class>
    void registerFileHandler(Class* p, void (Class::*func)(string), string ext)
    {
        using namespace std::placeholders; //for _1, _2, _3...
        handlers[ext] = std::bind(func, p, _1);
    }
private:
    map<string, std::function<void(string)> > handlers;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child()
    {
        registerFileHandler(this, &Child::loadJpg, "jpg");
        registerFileHandler(this, &Child::loadPNG, "png");
    }
    void loadJpg(string filename)
    {
        cout << "loading the jpeg "<< filename << endl;
    }
    void loadPNG(string filename)
    {
        cout << "loading the png "<< filename << endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Child child;
    child.load("blah.jpg");
    child.load("blah.png");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually would like some one to tell me how to use std::function. "typedef std::function<void(Parent&, string)> memFuncPtr;" doesn't work since I am passing  a function of type "void(Child&, string)

Comment: If `Child::loadJpg` isn't static, you need an actual `Child` object. How is `Parent` going to know which one to use? Is it `dynamic_cast<Child*>(this)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
class Parent
{
public:

    void registerFileHandler(string ext, const std::function<void(string)> &f)
    {
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child()
    {
        using namespace std::placeholders; //for _1, _2, _3...
        registerFileHandler("jpg", std::bind(&Child::loadJpg, this, _1));
        registerFileHandler("png", std::bind(&Child::loadPNG, this, _1));
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Somewhat overkill. Though it of course adds nice flexibility.

Comment: This is the one I went for. I just integrated Jan Hudecs template function to keep the potentially confusing C++x11 stuff away from the user.

Answer (score 4):

You need *some* form of type erasure. Assuming you can't use any of the sophisticated ones that already exist (`boost::function`, `std::function`) then you can roll your own:

```
class MemFuncPtr {
    void *obj;
    void (*caller)(void*, string);
  public:
    MemFuncPtr(void *obj, void(*caller)(void*, string)) : obj(obj), caller(caller) {}
    void operator()(string filename) {
        caller(obj, filename);
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    Child()
    {
        registerFileHandler("jpg", MemFuncPtr(this, &jpgcaller));
        registerFileHandler("png", MemFuncPtr(this, &pgncaller));
    }
    void loadJpg(string filename);
    void loadPNG(string filename);
  private:
    static void jpgcaller(void *obj, string filename) {
        static_cast<Child*>(obj)->loadJpg(filename);
    }
    static void pngcaller(void *obj, string filename) {
        static_cast<Child*>(obj)->loadPng(filename);
    }
};
```

I think you could get rid of those `static` functions using a function template with a pointer-to-member template parameter. But I'd probably make a mess of that code if I wrote it without testing it...

Comment: @JanHudec: then your answer will get more upvotes than mine, should you write it ;-)

Comment: Hm, you are right; it won't cast down automatically and it does not appear to be correct, the fact that MFC is doing it all over the place notwithstanding.

Comment: @JanHudec: You had me reasonably convinced, though. You can `static_cast` it, and I tried a case with multiple inheritance and `loadJpg` received the correct value of `this` even when called on a base pointer such that `(void*)baseptr != (void*)childptr`. So there's obviously a mechanism going on there (thunk/trampoline code? Or maybe just gubbins in the pointer-to-member-function) to make it work.

Comment: @JanHudec: 5.2.9/9 in C++03 (/12 in C++11) says that this works for pointer-to-member, even if the base class doesn't contain the member. But it doesn't explicitly mention pointer-to-member-function.

Comment: Thanks. I've found the clause for the opposite direction in 4.11/2, but missed this one again. I've already looked it up once, because I wanted to know whether the use in MFC is broken because it's invalid or because the compiler violates the spec. And I didn't remember it properly. It appears to be the compiler after all.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of suggestions on how to work around passing in the function pointer - could you may be redesign slightly - and use inheritance properly..

```
class FileLoader
{
  virtual void load() = 0; // real load function
};

class LoadManager
{
  // Here is your registry
  std::map<std::string, std::uniqe_ptr<FileLoader>> _loaders;
};

class JpegLoader : public FileLoader
{
};

class BitmapLoader : public FileLoader
{
};

// etc.

// Now register these with the LoadManager and use from there...
```

Does this design not seem a little clearer? Obviously this suggestion is based on the simple snippet you've posted there, if your architecture is more complicated, then it's different story...

Comment: If each class only handles one type I would only need classic Polymorphism.

Comment: But, I stated in the question that I want one class to be able to register N callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, `registerFileHandler()` should pass a pointer to the actual child object that will load the image.

Probably better would be to define `static Child Child::loadPNG(string filename)` but it depends on what the Child and Parent objects really do.

Comment: Actually it does not need to. The registration is done on `this` only, so it will be `this`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Child;  // unfortunately this is needed

class Parent
{
public:
    void registerFileHandler(string ext, void (Child::*mem_fn) (string), Child* obj) {
                                       // ^^^^the member func  ^^^^^^^^  //the object to be used 
         (obj->*mem_fn)("test");
    }
};


class Child : public Parent
{
    Child()
    {
        registerFileHandler("jpg", &Child::loadJpg, this);
        registerFileHandler("png", &Child::loadPNG, this);
                                                            // You need to pass this.
    }
    void loadJpg(string filename);
    void loadPNG(string filename);
};
```

---

However what you are doing is probably an overkill. Is there any reason why you can't use something like this?

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void registerFileHandler(string ext)  = 0;
};


class Child : public Parent
{
    Child()
    {
        registerFileHandler("jpg");
        registerFileHandler("png");
    }
    void loadJpg(string filename);
    void loadPNG(string filename);

    virtual void registerFileHandler(string ext)   {
        loadJpg(ext);
        loadJpg(ext);
    }
};
```

Comment: Generally you have have more than one child.

Comment: And "Parent doesn't know about Child".

Comment: @bgp2000 That's why you have to forward declare it, as it says unfortunately.

Comment: @bgp2000 But may I ask why not make registerFileHandler virtual and define it as pure virtual in Parent? Implement it in children. Wouldn't that be easier

Comment: @bgp2000 See the edit. Doesn't that cover the same thing? why go to all this trouble?

Comment: Parent can't know about Child since Parent resides in a library and Child is user code written at a later point.

Comment: It doesn't cover the same thing. registerFileHandler() isn't suppose to call loadJpg() immediately with the argument "jpg". At a later point, when it finds a file with the extension "jpg it should call loadJpg with the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration-wise, you can get away with

```
class Parent
{
public:
    template <typename Child>
    void registerFileHandler(string ext, void (Child::*memFuncPtr)(string filename));
};
```

That doesn't solve the problem how to store those pointers, of course. One common solution is

```
struct Handler {
   virtual ~Handler() { };
  virtual void Load(Parent*, std::string) = 0;
};
template<typename Child>
struct ChildHandler {
  void (Child::*memFuncPtr)(string filename);
  virtual void Load(Parent* p, string filename) {
      dynamic_cast<Child&>(*p).*memFuncPtr(filename);
  }
};
```

This is of course yet another form of type erasure.

Comment: I'm guessing that `ChildHander<Child>` will need to be dynamically allocated. If so then either `Handler` needs a virtual destructor or else you *could* manage the pointer with `shared_ptr<Handler>`, which captures the pointer type passed to its constructor. `unique_ptr<Handler>` does *not* capture the pointer type passed to the constructor.

Comment: Why on earth you are doing those casts yourself when the compiler can do them for you, implicitly?

Comment: @Jan: there's only one cast in this code. That's the downward `dynamic_cast`, which can't be implicit.

Comment: @SteveJessop: No, it isn't implicit, but it is not needed. Nor is the template.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Valid point on the virtual destructor. That too is a form of type erasure, and it really doesn't make sense to use two different mechanisms. Added `~Handler` to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent
{
public:
    // so we don't need to static-cast at the call site
    template <typename ChildT>
    void registerFileHandler(string ext, void (ChildT::*func)(string)) {
         doRegisterFileHandler(ext, static_cast<void (Parent::*func)(string)>(func));
    }
    void doRegisterFileHandler(string ext, void (Parent::*func)(string));
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    Child()
    {
        registerFileHandler("jpg", &Child::loadJpg);
        registerFileHandler("png", &Child::loadPNG);
    }
    void loadJpg(string filename);
    void loadPNG(string filename);
};
```

You call the function as usual:

```
this->*func(string)
```

in parent.

The specification says this should work (5.2.9/9 in C++03, 5.2.9/12 in C++11) and MFC uses it in the message map. Yet Microsoft Visual C++ is the compiler where it actually does *not* work in all cases. Because Microsoft came up with this "minimal representation of member pointers", where the pointer to member is represented differently depending on whether the class uses multiple inheritance or virtual inheritance or not. So if the child uses multiple inheritance, but parent does not, the cast cannot be done, because pointer to member of class with multiple inheritance does not fit into pointer to member of class with single inheritance. There is a compiler option to always use generic format, but code compiled with and without it is binary incompatible.

Comment: I like the signature of the template functions. It keeps the user code very simple. I don't like the static_cast, but decided std::bind was the safe way to go.

Comment: @bgp2000: `std::bind` is significantly more flexible, allowing you to implement the loaders in separate objects. Which is probably better design here. At some cost at runtime, which does not matter here, but could matter for something you do in tight loop millions of times a second.